# This is my client and server side code. I don't know why I am getting error "Connect Failed" after running the client code for second time

Tags: c, client-server

Server.c

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <time.h> 

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
int listenfd = 0, connfd = 0;
struct sockaddr_in serv_addr; 

char sendBuff[1025];
time_t ticks; 

listenfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
memset(&serv_addr, '0', sizeof(serv_addr));
memset(sendBuff, '0', sizeof(sendBuff)); 

serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
serv_addr.sin_port = htons(5000); 

bind(listenfd, (struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)); 

listen(listenfd, 10); 

while(1)
{
    connfd = accept(listenfd, (struct sockaddr*)NULL, NULL); 

    ticks = time(NULL);
    snprintf(sendBuff, sizeof(sendBuff), "%.24s\r\n", ctime(&ticks));
    write(connfd, sendBuff, strlen(sendBuff)); 

    close(connfd);
    sleep(1);
 }
```

}

Client.c

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h> 

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
int sockfd = 0, n = 0;
char recvBuff[1024];
struct sockaddr_in serv_addr; 

if(argc != 2)
{
    printf("\n Usage: %s <ip of server> \n",argv[0]);
    return 1;
} 

memset(recvBuff, '0',sizeof(recvBuff));
if((sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0)
{
    printf("\n Error : Could not create socket \n");
    return 1;
} 

memset(&serv_addr, '0', sizeof(serv_addr)); 

serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
serv_addr.sin_port = htons(5000); 

if(inet_pton(AF_INET, argv[1], &serv_addr.sin_addr)<=0)
{
    printf("\n inet_pton error occured\n");
    return 1;
} 

if( connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
{
   printf("\n Error : Connect Failed \n");
   return 1;
} 

while ( (n = read(sockfd, recvBuff, sizeof(recvBuff)-1)) > 0)
{
recvBuff[n] = 0;
if(fputs(recvBuff, stdout) == EOF)
  {
   printf("\n Error : Fputs error\n");
  }
} 

if(n < 0)
{
printf("\n Read error \n");
} 

return 0;
}
```

After executing the server code first and then the client code gives me day,date and time. But when I execute the server code and then client code for second time, it gives error "Error : Connect Failed"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Close the "sockfd" once you done with it.

Comment: What arguments have to be passed in "sockfd" function while closing it?